# NullPointerException in vaadin table?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm having a problem with vaadin table. When I change row of values displayed returns NullPointerException and I don't know why. In vaadin book chapter5 Table, there a method setNullSelectionAllowed(false) when this problem happens, but still doesn't work to me.

```
// Table configs
Table tabela = new Table();
tabela.setSizeFull();       
tabela.addContainerProperty("Aperfeiçoamento", String.class, null);
tabela.addContainerProperty("Entidade", String.class, null);
tabela.addContainerProperty("Início", String.class, null);
tabela.addContainerProperty("Conclusão", String.class, null);   
tabela.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
tabela.setImmediate(true);
tabela.setSelectable(true);
tabela.setColumnReorderingAllowed(false);
tabela.addValueChangeListener(this);

@Override
public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    /** preenche os campos do formulario com o id do aperfeicoamento */
    String id = event.getProperty().getValue().toString();
    List<Aperfeicoamento> lista = new AperfeicoamentoDAO().getAperfeicoamentoById(Integer.parseInt(id));
    if(!lista.isEmpty()){
        try{
            for(Aperfeicoamento apf : lista){
                aperfeicoamento.setValue(apf.getAperfeicoamento());
                entidadeEnsino.setValue(apf.getEntidadeEnsino());
                cidade.setValue(apf.getCidade());
                comboEstado.setValue(apf.getEstado());
                inicio.setValue(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(apf.getInicio()));
                conclusao.setValue(!apf.getConclusao().isEmpty() ? new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(apf.getConclusao()) : null);    
            }
        }catch(ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// DAO
/** retorna uma lista de perfeicoamento por id e cpf */
public List<Aperfeicoamento> getAperfeicoamentoById(Integer id){
    List<Aperfeicoamento> lista = new ArrayList<Aperfeicoamento>();     
    try{
        PreparedStatement stm = this.con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM aperfeicoamento WHERE idAperfeicoamento = ? AND cpf = ?");         
        stm.setInt(1, id);
        stm.setString(2, SessionCurriculum.getCpfInSession());
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            Aperfeicoamento apf = new Aperfeicoamento();
            apf.setIdAperfeicoamento(rs.getInt("idAperfeicoamento"));
            apf.setAperfeicoamento(rs.getString("aperfeicoamento"));
            apf.setEntidadeEnsino(rs.getString("entidadeensino"));
            apf.setCidade(rs.getString("cidade"));
            apf.setEstado(rs.getString("estado"));
            apf.setInicio(new ControlaDatas().getDataFormatada(rs.getString("inicio")));
            apf.setConclusao(rs.getString("conclusao") == null ? null : new ControlaDatas().getDataFormatada(rs.getString("conclusao")));
            lista.add(apf);
        }
        rs.close();
        stm.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        new Notification("Erro tentando select em aperfeiçoamento <br/>", e.getLocalizedMessage(), Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE, true).show(Page.getCurrent());          
    }
    return lista;
}
```

> ```
> com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method valueChange in br.ind.ibg.curriculunsibg.views.CursosView
> ```
>
> failed.   at
>   com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:528)
>     at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:167)     at
>   com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:969)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.fireValueChange(AbstractField.java:1126)
>     at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.setValue(AbstractField.java:542)     at
>   com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSelect.setValue(AbstractSelect.java:702)    at
>   com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSelect.changeVariables(AbstractSelect.java:521)
>     at com.vaadin.ui.Table.changeVariables(Table.java:2880)     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:396)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleBurst(ServerRpcHandler.java:221)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:111)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:91)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1371)
>     at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   br.ind.ibg.curriculunsibg.views.CursosView.valueChange(CursosView.java:304)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
>     ... 27 more

Any idea ?

Comment: which row causes NullPointerException?

Comment: all rows causes. The NullPointerException happens when I change select

Comment: show us the stacktrace of the error. What do you mean change select?

Comment: I posted the stacktrace !!!

Comment: the following line looks suspiciously:
br.ind.ibg.curriculunsibg.views.CursosView.valueChange(CursosView.java:304)

could you please paste the source?

Comment: @wypieprz I solved the problem. I was trying execute one test with value empty when that value really has a null value. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write setNullSelectionAllowed(false) it does not mean that there will always be some item selected.
In you case to avoid NPE:

- use setNullSelectionItemId() to set some default value
- check if some item is selected with if(event.getProperty().getValue() != null)

Comment: I did try do this, but still doesn't work.
<code>
  tabela = new Table();
  tabela.setSizeFull();  
  tabela.addContainerProperty("Aperfeiçoamento", String.class, null);
  tabela.addContainerProperty("Entidade", String.class, null);
  tabela.addContainerProperty("Início", String.class, null);
  tabela.addContainerProperty("Conclusão", String.class, null); 
  tabela.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
  tabela.setImmediate(true);
  tabela.setSelectable(true);
  tabela.setColumnReorderingAllowed(false);
  tabela.setNullSelectionItemId(new String("0"));
  tabela.addValueChangeListener(this);
</code>